# Ubuntu not turning on after installing bumblebee

Tags: boot, gpu, bumblebee

I have installed bumblebee to switch between Gpu but after reboot the laptop is stack on the Ubuntu and Gp logo.
What can I do ?

Comment: Use the live media and boot to a safe mode. I can only find this as a windows app where did you get it?

Comment: Can I do something from the bios without reinstalling ubuntu ?

Comment: No that is not possible.